# Intellij not able to identify root folder when SBT build is used

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

Below is my project structure. I'm trying to read my properties file `pgmproperties.properties` in my program below but getting error `File Not found`. Please tell me where should i place my file. I'm using SBT build tool.

[image]

My code

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // This is used to read Properties files and get the values
    val is: InputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("pgmproperties.properties")
    val prop: Properties = new Properties()
    if (is != null) {
      prop.load(is)
    }
    else {
      throw new FileNotFoundException("Properties file cannot be loaded")
    }
    val sndrmailid = prop.getProperty("SndrMailId")      //Sender Mail id
    val psswd      = prop.getProperty("SndrMailPsswd")   //Sender gmail Mailbox id password
    val tomailid   = prop.getProperty("RcvrMailId")      // Receiver email id.

     println( sndrmailid )   
  }
```

Error getting
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The right place where to put resources is: `src/main/resources` (as said in the official SBT [documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html)).
Try to move your file there and it should work :)

Comment: Its not working.

Comment: True but OP also has to NOT use `getSystemResourceAsStream` in favour of a regular `getResourceAsStream`